# Pinescript: Plotting conditional arrow within table

Tags: pine-script

I'm struggling to plot an arrow within a table which is either up or down, dependent upon a condition.

I attempted this code but I think neither the arguments plotshope nor fillcell are appropriate.

Please can someone help me understand how to perform this.

````
f_fillCell(_table, _column, _row, _title, _value, _bgcolor, _txtcolor) =>
    _cellText = _title + '\n' + _value
    table.cell(_table, _column, _row, _cellText, bgcolor=_bgcolor, text_color=_txtcolor)

// Draw table
var bgcolor = color.new(color.black, 0)
if drawTable
    if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
        // Update table
        if tf1bull == true
        plotshape(divTable, 0, 1, (lbrTF1), tf1bull ? style=shape.arrowup, color=color.green : shape.arrowdown, color=color.red)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call plot functions in the local scope.

You can simply use arrows in the text field.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script",overlay=true)

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Apologies for the delay - I, proudly, found my way there after discovering the wonders of ascii.

Answer (score 0):

After some fannying around, I eventually discovered that I could use a wealth of ascii characters in the text field, thus conquering the problem.

Should it be of use to another, my final script was as follows:

````
if drawTable
    if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory and tf1bull == true and sigSlope1 == 0
        table.cell(divTable, 1, 0, ("TF" + lbrTF1 + " ᐱ"), text_color=color.red)
    else if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory and tf1bull == true and sigSlope1 == 1
        table.cell(divTable, 1, 0, ("TF" + lbrTF1 + " ᐱ"), text_color=color.green)

    else if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory and tf1bear == true and sigSlope1 == 1
        table.cell(divTable, 1, 0, ("TF" + lbrTF1 + " ᐯ"), text_color=color.green)
    else if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory and tf1bear == true and sigSlope1 == 0
        table.cell(divTable, 1, 0, ("TF" + lbrTF1 + " ᐯ"), text_color=color.red)
    ```
````